# How can I edit divs with 'contenteditable' property with Laravel Dusk?

Tags: laravel, selenium, laravel-dusk, laravel-testing

I have a wysiwyg editor in my project, that I need to test and it has a `contenteditable` property. I cant type directly, as it is a simple `<trix-editor>` tag:

```
<trix-editor input="28" placeholder="Type your message here..." contenteditable="" role="textbox" trix-id="2" toolbar="trix-toolbar-2">
</trix-editor>
```

As you can notice, it has `contenteditable` attribute. I can edit it easily with Selenium IDE when running Selenium tests and it shows command `edit content`.

Can the same be done with Laravel Dusk?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set value of `contenteditable` attribute?

Comment: The [edit content](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/selenium-ide/editcontent) command is only available in the Selenium IDE and the _Kantu_ Selenium IDE. I have not seen it in other tools like Laravel Dusk or Selenium itself.

Comment: @Andersson yes, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the content with [`keys()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/dusk#using-the-keyboard):

```php
$browser->keys('[trix-id="2"]', 'Text')
```